# CoreData ERROR : Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead

Tags: ios, core-data

I can't fix this error:

> Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

The problem is that the properties of the file xcdatamodeld file are set correctly

Look at this:

[image]

[image]

I don't understand the problem

Comment: Sidenote: Avoid using "new" in variable names, follow the naming conventions https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html

Comment: @Sneak no, because the properties of the entity I set as the answer to that question and doesn't work anyway

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The duplicate suggests multiple checks and answers. Update your question with what you have tried so far and why it didnt work. Also, looking at your screenshot, the error says -
 Unable to load class named **VDC.Questions** for entity **Questions** . What is **VDC**.Questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specify the Core Data entity `Questions` to be of class **Questions** (rather than **NSManagedObject**).  This is often done to add convenience property accessors and methods.

So you need to provide a Questions subclass of NSManagedObject (or just null the class name in the Core Data editor).

P.S. You probably want to label the class as `Question` (singular) rather than `Questions` (plural).